# Pydantic AttributeError: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'bodyKey'

Tags: python, pydantic

Code I am trying to run:

```
from typing import ClassVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class IndexSchema(BaseModel):
    bodyKey: str = Field(..., description="Body Key in the data")


class Index(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Name of the index")
    schema: ClassVar[IndexSchema] = Field(..., description="schema of the data")

obj = Index(name="Rom",schema=IndexSchema(bodyKey="Rom is crazy"))
print(obj.name)
print(obj.schema.bodyKey)
```

While trying to run this code, getting the following error

```
Rom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rommonda/Desktop/Llama/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(obj.schema.bodyKey)
AttributeError: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'bodyKey'
```

Is there a way to make this work ?

PS: Using ClassVar[] because BaseModel also has an attribute named 'schema' so it will error out

Comment: `ClassVar` is not the thing you need here. It just tells that this variable is not the field of class instance, but this is a field of class (will have one value for all instances)

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic overrides this field in runtime.

If you need exactly this field name only for serialization reasons then you can use `alias`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class IndexSchema(BaseModel):
    bodyKey: str = Field(..., description="Body Key in the data")


class Index(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Name of the index")
    index_schema: IndexSchema = Field(..., description="schema of the data", alias="schema")

obj = Index(name="Rom", index_schema=IndexSchema(bodyKey="Rom is crazy"))
print(obj.name)
print(obj.index_schema.bodyKey)

obj2 = Index.model_validate({"name": "Rom", "schema": {"bodyKey" : "Rom is crazy"}})

print(obj2.name)
print(obj2.index_schema.bodyKey)
```

I can't run and check this code right now, but it should work.

And if you need to use exactly `schema` field name in your code, you can patch Pydantic like shown below. `schema` method is depricated in Pydantic-2 and I think you can remove it (but i'm not sure):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

delattr(BaseModel, "schema") # this will remove deprecated `schema` method from your models

class IndexSchema(BaseModel):
    bodyKey: str = Field(..., description="Body Key in the data")


class Index(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Name of the index")
    schema: IndexSchema = Field(..., description="schema of the data")

obj = Index(name="Rom", schema=IndexSchema(bodyKey="Rom is crazy"))
print(obj.name)
print(obj.schema.bodyKey)
```

Comment: Hi @Yurii thanks for your reply, the above code should works however the compulsion is to print(obj.schema.bodyKey) and cannot change the name "schema" to "index_schema" :)

Comment: You can use `schema_` instead of `index_schema`, but you can not use the name `schema` because it is already in use by Pydantic.

Comment: I found the way how to implement this. I updated my answer.